# Methods to find out which (configuration) files are read by executable when started

Tags: files, daemon, debugging

What are the clever ways to find out which (configuration) files are read by executable if started? For example `snmpd` or `sshd`. One option is probably to check the `CONFIGURATION FILES` or `FILES` section on a manual page. The other one, which I thought will work, is to trace the system calls, but at least in case of `snmpd`, this does not seem to work:

```
root@vserver:~# strace 2>&1 /usr/sbin/snmpd | grep snmpd.conf
root@vserver:~#
```

Last but not least, `stat` command does not help either because file access time is not updated. If it was updated, one could get some indication of possible configuration files by executing `find /etc/ -type f -amin 1`.
Any other ways to find out which (configuration) files are read by executable when started?

Comment: have a look at the `lsof` command

Comment: Add the `-f` option to `strace`. See also `autrace` when the service involves running setuid/setgid executables.

Comment: Read the source. Or as a short cut, run `strings $(which command)`. Both these will produce a lot more strings than `strace -f -e trace=open`, but may include files that are not opened on every run (conditional paths). Analysing the source is the only sure way to do it, there may be some tools to help.

Comment: What specific services are you looking to do this for, if any? Often times they'll provide their own mechanisms, such as `httpd`. For example it provides the `-V` switch which shows the conf file that it will start with. You'll have to look through the various service's "include" files if they offer such a mechanism, with this approach.

Comment: `lsof` would be helpful, but often times the conf files are open/read/closed so you could miss it with that approach. `lsof -p $(pidof <exec>)`.

Answer (score 5):

A general way is using `strace`:

```
strace -fe trace=open,openat <command>
```

Configuration files often ends with `.conf`. So you can filter the result by piping to `grep '\.conf`.

Another option, using `strings`:

```
$ strings $(which httpd) | grep '\.conf'
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
conf/httpd.conf
        Allowed in *.conf 
        directive in your httpd.conf file to list a non-root
```

Many programs also have an option for you to know what configuration file it read, example with `apache`:

```
$ httpd -V | grep '\.conf'
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Apache will show this with the `-V` switch so you don't have to `strings` the exec. Eg. `httpd -V | grep '\.conf'`.

Comment: @slm: Yes, but maybe others programs don't have option like apache `-V` switch, so I give a more general.

Comment: Yup, that's what I figured, but you might want to show it in a general form so that they understand it can be used in that manner, or make a comment that it can be used for other execs too.

Comment: @slm: Oh, good point. Added to my answer.

Comment: As a note, strace has a `file` expression that matches any system call that takes a full path. `strace -fefile your.command.here` will show you every path the program checks, so for instance if it's doing `access` or `stat` calls to check for existence you'll see what it's looking for. If it's doing its own bulk scanning with `getdents` strace can't show you exactly what it's looking for, but it can at least show you where it's looking.